# i tried creating an Ippa file on Appollo but i got an error

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, command-line-interface

This is my first time of building the ippa file

THE ERROR MESSAGE

Error: Sources update - Error updating sources - Error code 74
Your build has failed, to access logs run : appollo build logs 12KP
Appollo identified an error. You can ask for help regarding this issue here:
https://appollo.space/builds/0ab1a62022f745c686fe5c6804d918c2/help/

Answer (score 0):

The error "[!] Unable to find a target named RunnerTests in project Runner.xcodeproj, did find Runner" is because Flutter changed some things in version 3.10 and is now looking for RunnerTests, which was not created when you made the project in a previous version of flutter. You can either try to run the build with another version of flutter (by specifying the --flutter argument or adding flutter= in a .odevio file), or you need to regenerate the ios directory by deleting it, running flutter create --platform ios . (using flutter 3.10) then reapplying your changes to the ios directory (Info.plist and Podfile for example)

Source: https://github.com/Odevio/Odevio-CLI/issues/34

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work. In the `appollo build` command, I used the latest version of flutter before 3.10.0 which was 3.7.12. This is because flutter 3.10.0 is where a change was introduced that caused our problem.

I then ran the configuration build with the latest version of flutter below 3.10.0 (looked up [here](https://flutter-ko.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases)):

`appollo build start --flutter 3.7.12  --build-type ad-hoc`

I then had some version conflicts with some of my dependencies that required Dart SDK 3.0.0 but only 2.9.x was available with flutter version 3.7.12.

```
Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 2.19.0.

Because no versions of json_serializable match >6.7.1 <7.0.0 and json_serializable 6.7.1 requires SDK version ^3.0.0, json_serializable ^6.7.1 is 
forbidden.
So, because <myappp> depends on json_serializable ^6.7.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed
```

I had to downgrade the following packages to latest versions that support Dart SDK < 3.0.0. To find this info I had to look at the versions page of each package in my dependency list. Here is an example. Your package version conflict issues may be different from mine:

https://pub.dev/packages/http/versions

The resulting changes in my pubsec.yaaml are shown in diff below:

```
diff --git a/pubspec.yaml b/pubspec.yaml
index 375a0d6..02e1750 100644
--- a/pubspec.yaml
+++ b/pubspec.yaml
@@ -37,7 +37,7 @@ dependencies:
   # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
   cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
   thermostat: ^1.1.5
-  http: ^1.1.0
+  http: ^0.13.6
 
   retrofit: ^4.0.1
   logger: any  #for logging purpose
@@ -45,6 +45,7 @@ dependencies:
   retrofit_generator: ^7.0.8
   dio: ^5.2.1+1
   pretty_dio_logger: ^1.3.1
+  shared_preferences: ^2.2.0
 
 dev_dependencies:
   flutter_test:
@@ -58,7 +59,7 @@ dev_dependencies:
   flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
 
   build_runner: '>=2.3.0 <4.0.0'
-  json_serializable: ^6.7.1
+  json_serializable: ^6.6.2
 
 # For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
 # following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
```

I then ran the configuration build with the latest version of flutter below 3.10.0 (looked up [here](https://flutter-ko.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases)):

`appollo build start --flutter 3.7.12  --build-type ad-hoc`

And I got success with the download link for ipa file and the QR code.